# How do you package external libraries in your .Net projects?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-management, refix

A lot of my projects contain the Castle/NHibernate/Rhino-Tools stack. What's confusing about this is that Castle depends on some NHibernate libraries, NHibernate depends on some Castle libraries, and Rhino-Tools depends on both.

I've built all three projects on my machine, but I feel that copying the NHibernate/Castle libraries is a bit redundant since I built Rhino-Tools using the resulting libraries from my NHibernate and Castle builds.

Right now, I include all projects in seperate folders in my /thirdparty/libs folder in my project tree. Should I simply just have /thirdparty/libs/rhino-tools in my project and use the Castle/NHibernate libs from there? That would seem to make logical sense in not duplicating files, but I also like having each project in it's own distinct folder.

What are your views on this?

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the problems that we're trying to tackle in the [Refix open source project on CodePlex](http://refix.codeplex.com).

The idea is that Refix will parse all the projects in your solution, and before your project compiles, copy the necessary binaries from a single local repository on your machine into a folder within the solution tree and point the projects at them. This way, there's no need to commit the binaries. Your local Refix repository will pull binaries from a remote one (we're setting one up at repo.refixcentral.com), and you can set up an intermediate one for your team/department/company that can hold any additional software not held centrally.

It will also try to resolve conflicting version numbers - Visual Studio can be *too* forgiving of mismatched component version numbers, leading to solutions that compile but fall over at run time when they fail to load a dependency because two different versions would be needed.

So to answer the question "how do you package external libraries in your .Net projects", our vision is that you don't - you just include a Refix step in your build script, and let it worry about it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I use a folder for each, which seems to be the convention.

1. Does it really make a difference if you're copying them?
2. What if you want to switch one out? Let's say you go with a new O/R mapper. It will be much easier to just delete the NHibernate folder than to selectively delete DLLs in your Rhino-Tools folder.
3. Take this to it's logical conclusion and you won't have any folder organization in your lib folder since everything uses log4net :)

Comment: So would you delete all the Castle/NHibernate libs from the Rhino-Tools folder if you're keeping the other folders? I guess what I'm getting at is how to organize the thirdparty dependencies without tons of duplication.

Comment: Nope. I like thinking of them as atomic units. Have you run into a problem because of the duplication? If not, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Add additional probing paths to your app.config files to locate the dependency dlls. This way your can get away with having just one copy of everything you want. Though there are some quirks to using this feature (you must create the folder structure in a certain way). Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374182.aspx) for more details on the  tag.

Answer (score 1):

I will definetly recommend having a thirdparty or vendor folder in each of your project trees. If you find it annoying to have 32 copies of the rhino-tools package, you can have a single copy of it in your code repository, and do external references to it in your project tree.

Lets say you are using SVN, you can make a repository called "thirdparty libs" and in this have versioned copies of the libs. You then make an external property on your "thirdparty"-folder in your project tree which then in turn automaticly will do a check out of your centralized thirdparty libs. This way you for instance only have to update in one place if a security or a bugfix comes out, but each project is still in command of choosing which thirdparty libs, and which versions to use.

About the deps internally in thirdparty libs, i wouldn't mind those. The first time you compile your project, and some of the libs arent copied to your bin-folder because of implicit dependencies you can add an external attribute into your bin-folder, which will then automaticly check out the missing libs. That way you still only have to update your thirdparty libs in one place.